# In which languages is `if (x)` a legal test for nonzero value?

Tags: if-statement, language-design

I'm curious how universal the language paradigm is of allowing plain `if (x) ...` to check for nonzero value (on an *integer* variable, at least)?
(as opposed to explicitly requiring an operator: `if (x != 0)`)

Motivated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992844/should-i-test-1-or-0) which was tagged as language-agnostic, but that's strictly not even 100% correct for languages currently in common use, although it's close-enough. Is this *always* true of weakly-typed languages?

(Assume that x has been defined so we don't need to worry about that or exceptions. x may not necessarily have been initialized but consider that a separate case.)

Here is a summary:

```
C/C++, PERL, Python, PHP, Ruby, BASIC: Yes
C#, Java; Pascal, Modula-2 & other descendants of Pascal: illegal - must be Boolean
Fortran: Illegal syntax - must be Boolean
LISP: All integers considered true, nil considered false.
bash: Legal, but beware 0 signifies command success and nonzero signifies failure
```

Comment: @the downvoter, this is a legitimate question about weak typing philosophy in language design; also about the specific interpretation of True/False when testing an integer expression. I think it's useful to challenge the belief that the way the C language family does things is language-agnostic...

Comment: I'll leave this open to catch some more languages if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition must be Boolean in: C#, Java; Pascal, Modula-2 & other descendants of Pascal

The condition can be integer in: Basic (lacks Boolean)

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of other languages that don't use this idiom.

For example, in various Lisps (including Clojure) nil is considered a false value but all integers are considered true:

```
(if nil "True" "False")
=> "False"

(if 0 "True" "False")
=> "True"
```

Answer (score 1):

This made me think of Ruby.

```
a = 0
b = 5

if a
    p "true!"
end

if b
    p "true!"
end
```

Will both print "true!". Then there's that sweet `.zero?` method:

```
a.zero?
=> true
b.zero?
=> false
```